# Can not write to java txt file

Tags: java, bluej

I am currently using blueJ to learn java and I have an assignment where I have to write to a txt file, check if the file exists and read the file. The code I have is below which compiles but when I try to run the write() method,I receive the follow error  java.lang.nullpointerexception;

I do not know where I am going wrong and it is beginning to drive me nuts at this stage.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadWrite
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private String file;
private String text;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class ReadWrite
 */
public ReadWrite(String file, String text)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    file=this.file;
    text=this.text;
}

public void write() 
{


    try{
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        writer.write(text);
        writer.write('\n');
        writer.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }


}

public boolean writeToFile()
{

    boolean ok;

    try{

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        {
          write();
        }

        ok=true;
    }

    catch(IOException e) {

        ok=false;

    }

    return ok;

    }

public void read(String fileToRead)
{
    try {
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new        FileReader(fileToRead));
         String line = reader.readLine();

           while(line != null) {
               System.out.println(line);
               line = reader.readLine();
            }

            reader.close();

                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException e) {


                }  
                catch(IOException e) {

                } 
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: check the link, also, it's better if you paste complete stacktrace and the line causing the exception

Comment: look at the stacktrace. (Catch exceptions like e.printStackTrace(); instead of using System.out.println(e));  Because then it will tell you where the problem is located, instead of just the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor is assigning the values in reverse.  At the moment you have

```
public ReadWrite(String file, String text)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    file=this.file;
    text=this.text;
}
```

This is assigning the incoming variables `file` and `text` to the instance variables, which are null.

What you need to have is this:

```
public ReadWrite(String file, String text)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    this.file = file;
    this.text = text;
}
```

A useful way to avoid this in the future is to make your parameters `final` - this means you can't assign anything to them, and you'll catch this in the compiler.

```
public ReadWrite(final String file, final String text)
{
    // won't compile!
    file = this.file;
    text = this.text;
}
```

A further improvement would be to make the instance variables `file` and `text` `final`, which means they **have** to be assigned.  This way, you're using the compiler to help you catch errors.

```
public class ReadWrite
{
    private final String file;
    private final String text;

    public ReadWrite(final String file, 
                     final String text)
    {
        this.file = file;
        this.text = text;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million Steve, I can not believe I had the value in reverse! I could of looked at this for a week and still not have noticed!

Comment: Next up, you're going to find your `writer.close();` should be in a `finally` block, or a `try-with-resource`.

Comment: Yes i figured that bit out later on when reviewing my code, thanks for the help.